# Free Disk Space Error Trying to Extract Elevation Raster

Tags: r, elevatr

I am trying to create an elevation raster in order to calculate terrain ruggedness index (TRI) for a set of point data. My set of point data is somewhat large (14,630 observations) and spans most of the southwest US. Example code below:

```
#load packages
library(geodata)
library(elevatr)
library(raster)

#simulate point data
longitude<-runif(n=14630, min=-115.4333, max=-108.6997)
latitude<-runif(n=14630, min=32.45918, max=37.20805)
pts<-data.frame(longitude,latitude)

#change dataframe to a spatial points object
coordinates(pts) = c("longitude", "latitude") # specify column names
class(pts)

#definining the lonlat projection
prj_dd <- "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83"


#download a raster layer using the spatialpoints object as input
#zoom specifies the resolution
elevation <- get_elev_raster(pts, z = 13,prj=prj_dd,override_size_check=TRUE)
```

The issue is that when I use the `get_elev_raster` function from the elevatr package, I keep getting the following error:

> Error in sf::gdal_utils(util = "warp", source = files, destination = destfile,  :
> gdal_utils warp: an error occured

> In addition: Warning message:

> In CPL_gdalwarp(source, destination, options, oo, doo, quiet, "-overwrite" %in%  :
> GDAL Error 3: C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmps3PYwn\file32b8e4c79d6.tif: Free disk space available is 8839901184 bytes, whereas 21476933632 are at least necessary. You can disable this check by defining the CHECK_DISK_FREE_SPACE configuration option to FALSE.

This leads me to believe that the raster I am trying to download is too large. Am I right about that, and if so, is there any way I can reduce the size of the raster while still getting the necessary elevation data (elevation of the cell containing point data as well as its eight surrounding cells) or free up disk space? Thanks!

Comment: I'll ask the obvious question: how big is your hard drive and how much free space is there on it? This might be on  the main OS (`C:/` in windows, `/` in all others) or it might be in the project-directory where-ever you are working.

Comment: You can try a smaller z which will result in a smaller raster or split your input data into smaller areas.  That being said, like @r2evans suggests, you appear to be running low on space.  You only have 8GB free and your request needs at least 21GB.  If you have another drive available to you with more space, the development version (https://github.com/jhollist/elevatr) allows you to specify a temp directory with tmp_dir instead of using the default temp location for your OS.

Comment: I did try to clean up space on my OS, but now the required disk space has gone up to 39636172800. I do have about 78 GB of free disk space on my main OS. I had the properties tab of my drive open and watched the available disk space drop from 78 to 22 GB before R aborted and gave me the same error. Is this still just a problem of not enough storage? I'll try to specify my external hard drive as a temporary directory if it still isn't working